# How to listen the requests sent to a unix socket

Tags: docker, macos, socket, ipc, unix-sockets

I'm learning docker and wanted to see the API commands sent by the client to the docker server/engine. I know that the communication between the two processes happens via `/var/run/docker.sock`. Is there a way to check what commands are being sent via the socket to the server?

Comment: See [Can I monitor a local unix domain socket like tcpdump?](https://superuser.com/questions/484671/can-i-monitor-a-local-unix-domain-socket-like-tcpdump)